# inconsistent shipping charge calculation in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

Enabled shipping charge in my `Magento1.9` store is `table_rate` and `in store pickup`.

If As a login user I have added few items into my cart and logout. I login again and moving to cart page. It is not showing and shipping charges on cart screen. If I do refresh the same page, it shows shipping charges from `table rate`.

I logout and login again, moving to cart again shipping charges is not showing and do refresh it appears.

This seems inconsistent.

**Try 1#:** I disabled all custom modules and flushed cache. No luck

**Try 2#:** Disabled all custom modules switched to default theme (not rwd, magento default). Flushed cache. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue by a custom code to set `shipping_method` as `null`

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Ocra_CartShipping>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </Ocra_CartShipping>
        </modules>
        <global>
        <models>
            <ocra_cartshipping>
                <class>Ocra_CartShipping_Model</class>
            </ocra_cartshipping>
        </models>
            <events>
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <observers>
                    <ocra_cartshipping>
                        <class>ocra_cartshipping/observer</class>
                        <method>handleShippingMethod</method>
                    </ocra_cartshipping>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

`Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Ocra_CartShipping_Model_Observer {
    public function handleShippingMethod($observer) {


        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();


        if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'checkout_cart'){
            $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod(null);
            $shippingAddress->save();

            $saveQuote = true;
        }
    }
}
```